# 401 (Unauthorized) | Cosmos DB rest API | rest-from-.net

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am trying out [rest-from-.net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/d3f8e9c731bc92816d023719e7e780b7a9546ca2/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs#L151-L164) for Cosmos DB **Table API**.

Set the `endpoint`, `masterKey` , `databaseId` ,`collectionId` . I am using internal resource ids. Set `x-ms-version` as [2017-07-29](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#requests-authorized-using-azure-ad-shared-key-or-shared-key-lite).

Added the following before [line 84](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/d3f8e9c731bc92816d023719e7e780b7a9546ca2/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs#L84).

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
```

Now, it looks like below:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", utc_date);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-07-29");

//LIST all databases
verb = "GET";
resourceType = "dbs";
resourceId = string.Empty;
resourceLink = string.Format("dbs");

authHeader = GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType, masterKey, "master", "1.0");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", authHeader);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");

response = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(baseUri, resourceLink)).Result;
```

On the `GetStringAsync` call, I get 401.

```
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

- I have Contributor role on the Azure Cosmos DB account.
- I have gone through [this post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518959/cosmos-db-rest-api-error-401-unauthorized).
- [Querying Azure Cosmos DB resources using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#response-details) is for SQL API and not for Table API. But I have followed the relevant mentioned parts.

> Either the Authorization or x-ms-date header is not set. 401 is also returned when the Authorization header is set to an invalid authorization token.

- After reading [Diagnose and troubleshoot Azure Cosmos DB unauthorized exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-unauthorized), I have also tried using a regenerated Read-Write Primary Key.

Why is the authorization failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though [Querying Azure Cosmos DB resources using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api) describes usage of REST for Cosmos DB, such use of REST is possible only for SQL API not for Gremlin, Cassandra or Table API. Unfortunately, the document doesn't mention that. Hence, the authorization was failing. Instead refer [Table Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api).